# Ajax return status code 0 but script still working

Tags: php, ajax

I have one script called data.php which I am calling from ajax to refresh database. When we call that script its empty database table and adding new record in while loop. Its working fine but when I call from ajax. ajax giving me Error 0 after some records get inserted, However my script continue and inserting all records as expected but since my ajax stop working I am not getting success call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#button1', function(e){
        jQuery("#musicinfo1").toggle();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'data.php',
            //timeout: 300000,
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
            },
            success: function(data) {
              jQuery("#musicinfo1").toggle("slow");
              jQuery("#musicinfo").toggle("slow");
              
              //setTimeout('moomoo()', 1000);
          
            }
        });
    });
});

function moomoo() {
   location.reload();
}
</script>
```

This is my data.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("includes/connection.php");
require 'scraping.php';
$quotes_qry="SELECT * FROM tbl_url ORDER BY id ASC";
 
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$quotes_qry);

$q = "TRUNCATE TABLE `tbl_data`";
$resultnew=mysqli_query($mysqli,$q);

$i=0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $html = file_get_html($row['url']);
    $$html = file_get_html($row['url']);
    $url = $row['url'];
    $name= $html->find('h1[class=page-title]', 0)->plaintext;
    $one_year_return= $html->find('div[class=company-highlights--right-close]', 0)->plaintext;
    $property_type= $html->find('div[class=company-highlights--data-content]', 0)->plaintext;
    $company_type= $html->find('div[class=company-highlights--data-content]', 1)->plaintext;
    $exchange= $html->find('div[class=company-highlights--data-content]', 2)->plaintext;
    $listing_status= $html->find('div[class=company-highlights--data-content]', 3)->plaintext;
    $ticker= $html->find('div[class=company-highlights--data-content]', 4)->plaintext;
    $previous_closed= $html->find('.field--name-field-stock-price-prev-close .field__item', false)->getAttribute('content');
    $current_high= $html->find('.field--name-field-stock-price-current-high .field__item', false)->getAttribute('content');
    $current_low= $html->find('.field--name-field-stock-price-current-low .field__item', false)->getAttribute('content');
    
    $thirty_days_volume= $html->find('.field--name-field-30-days-average-volume .field__item', false)->getAttribute('content');
    
    $fifty_two_week_high= $html->find('.field--name-field-stock-52-week-high .field__item', false)->getAttribute('content');
    $fifty_two_week_low= $html->find('.field--name-field-stock-52-week-low .field__item', false)->getAttribute('content');
    
    $dividend_yield= $html->find('.field--name-field-stock-dividend-yield .field__item', false)->getAttribute('content');
    $previous_quarter= $html->find('.field--name-field-stock-funds-from-operation .field__item', false)->getAttribute('content');
    
    $count0 = count($html->find('div[field--name-field-stock-last-paid-div-value]', 0));
    if($count0 > 0){
        $last_paid_value= $html->find('.field--name-field-stock-last-paid-div-value .field__item', false)->getAttribute('content');
    }else{
        $last_paid_value = 0;
    }
    $days_volume = 0;
    $market_cap=0;
    
    $qry = "INSERT INTO tbl_data            
                        (`url`,`name`,`one_year_return`,`property_type`,
                        `company_type`,`exchange`,`listing_status`,
                        `ticker`, `previous_closed`,`current_high`,
                        `current_low`, `thirty_days_volume`,
                        `fifty_two_week_high`,`fifty_two_week_low`,
                        `last_paid_value`,`dividend_yield`,
                        `previous_quarter`,`days_volume`, `market_cap`) 
                VALUES ('$url','$name','$one_year_return',
                        '$property_type','$company_type','$exchange',
                        '$listing_status', '$ticker', '$previous_closed', 
                        '$current_high', '$current_low',
                        '$thirty_days_volume', '$fifty_two_week_high', 
                        '$fifty_two_week_low','$last_paid_value',
                        '$dividend_yield','$previous_quarter',
                        '$days_volume','$market_cap')";
    
    $result2= mysqli_query($mysqli,$qry);
    $i++;
}
echo "Data Refresh Done!";
?>
```

Comment: When you are having problems with code THIS LINE `error_reporting(0);` IS COUNTER PRODUCTIVE

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I am getting some warning so I have added error_reporting(0); as I have mentioned my script continue working even after ajax return 0 and finishing the job. so its matter and cause issue? Thanks!

Comment: If you get errors and warning, FIX THEM DONT HIDE THEM. What warnings?

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: You have gone very quiet, what warnings were you getting? They are probably relevant